# c# split/duplicate multi attachment outlook emails to individual emails with one attachment each

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am working on a workflow that deals with each PDF attachment as a separate order. It is written by others and I have no control over what happens in it. All it requires is that each of the outlook email must have one and only one PDF attachment.

As I can not amend the workflow, I have to split/duplicate any email that has multiple (2 or more) attachments and save copies of that original email one with each attachment.

I have tried the following, it creates copies but doesn't get rid of additional attachments from the copy.

```c#
foreach (var i in ordersFolder.Items)
{
    if((i is MailItem) == false)
    { 
        continue;
    }
    
    MailItem item = (MailItem)i;
    if (item.Attachments.Count > 1)
    {
        foreach (var attachment in item.Attachments)
        
            MailItem newMail = (MailItem)item.Copy(); //this works
            var restAttachments = newMail.Attachments.Where(x => x.FileName != attachment.FileName).ToList(); //this gives me list of all unwanted ones
            foreach (var restAttachmentItem in restAttachments)
            {
                var attachmentToRemove = newMail.Attachments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FileName == restAttachmentItem.FileName);
                var indexToRemove = attachmentToRemove.Index; //this returns 2
                newMail.Attachments.Remove(indexToRemove); //this doesn't work
            }
        }
    }
    
    //note - I noticed that there is a difference between zero-based index and 1 based index. so, after copying the email I tried the following and still didn't work
    newMail.Attachments.Remove(1); //no effect
    newMail.Attachments.Remove(2); //no effect
    
    //If you can help, please also, help with deleting the original multi-attachment email (MailItem item)
```

Comment: Try with  newMail.Attachments.RemoveAt(indexToRemove)

Comment: Hi I tried but Attachments doesnt contain a definition for RemoveAt, and intellisense asks me to change it back to Remove.
Don't think RemoveAt is a function in Attachments. thanks for your response though

Comment: Don't have a solution yet but I figured out why it won't remove the attachment from the copies or from the original email, as each of the copy is exact clone of the original one with same conversationID and conversation index. So, by the time wants to remove the attachment, there may be three emails with exact same metadata.

Comment: RemoveAt comes from List<T>. Attachments is a list? You can try to convert to a list if it any other type of IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, you can try the following code to remove the Specified attchment.

```
 foreach (Outlook.MailItem item in testFolder.Items)
        {
            if(item.Attachments.Count>1)
            {
                foreach (Outlook.Attachment attachment in item.Attachments)
                {
                    if(!attachment.FileName.Contains(".png"))
                    {
                        Outlook.MailItem newMail = item.Copy();
                        var restAttachments = newMail.Attachments.Cast<Outlook.Attachment>().Where(x => x.FileName != attachment.FileName).ToList(); //this gives me list of all unwanted ones
                        foreach (var restAttachmentItem in restAttachments)
                        {
                            var attachmentToRemove = newMail.Attachments.Cast<Outlook.Attachment>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.FileName == restAttachmentItem.FileName);
                            var indexToRemove = attachmentToRemove.Index;
                            newMail.Attachments.Remove(indexToRemove);
                            newMail.Save();

                        }
                    }
                   
                }
            }
           
        }
```

The code `if(!attachment.FileName.Contains(".png"))` is used to filter the png file out.

Note: Please remember save your email after you delete the attachment by using **newMail.Save** method.

Comment: Hi yes, this worked perfectly, as in creates separate emails
Only that if there were three or more attachments to start with it would create a blank newMail at the end. Trying to figure out but no avail so far.
May be I can put if clause saying if restattachment.count > 0 then only do 

foreach (var restAttachmentItem in restAttachments)
                     .........

Comment: Oh no, I just noticed it is not creating blank email without any attachment, it creates one extra cause of the logo in email signature - thinks image001.png is an attachment. 
Will try to filter that out, but if you know any way please let me know.

Comment: @rinuk, I have updated my code for filter the png file out. You can have a check.

Comment: Spot on - done. Thank you so much. It is solved.